# Moving from jquery-te-1.4.0 to CKeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm trying to move from jquery-te-1.4.0 to CKeditor (inline) and quite newbie with JS

The original code for jquery-te was:

```
        var stopBlur = false;
        a.html("<textarea "+title+"name=\"textarea\" id=\""+ a.attr('id') +"_field\">" + a.html() + "</textarea>");
        editor = a.find('textarea');
        editor.jqte({focus: function(){stopBlur=true;setTimeout(function(){stopBlur=false;},200);},blur: function(){setTimeout(function(){if(stopBlur)return;fieldSave(a.attr('id'),a.find('div.jqte_editor').html());},50)}});
        $('div.jqte_tool').click(function(){
            stopBlur = true;
            setTimeout(function(){stopBlur = false;},200);
            a.find('div.jqte_editor').focus();
        });
        a.find('div.jqte_editor').focus();
```

My current (non-functional) code is:

```
var stopBlur = false;
    a.html("<div "+title+"name=\"div\" id=\""+ a.attr('id') +"_field\" class=\"editable\" contenteditable=\"true\">" + a.html() + "</div>");
    editor = a.find('div');
    editor.ckeditor({focus: function(){stopBlur=true;setTimeout(function(){stopBlur=false;},200);},blur: function(){setTimeout(function(){if(stopBlur)return;fieldSave(a.attr('id'),a.find(div.ckeditor).html());},50)}});

    $('div.ckeditor').click(function(){
        stopBlur = true;
        setTimeout(function(){stopBlur = false;},200);
        a.find('div.ckeditor').focus();
    });
    a.find('div.ckeditor').focus();
```

As I said: my JS skills are quite poor and I have no idea how to get CK to save when stopBlur etc'
Help will be much apreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

I made a little progress:

```
        var stopBlur = false;
        a.html("<textarea "+title+"name=\"textarea\" id=\""+ a.attr('id') +"_field\" class=\"editable\" contenteditable=\"true\">" + a.html() + "</textarea>");
editor = a.find('textarea');
editor.ckeditor({focus: function(){stopBlur=true;setTimeout(function(){stopBlur=false;},200);},blur: function(){setTimeout(function(){if(stopBlur)return;fieldSave(a.attr('id'),a.find(div.ckeditor).html());},50)}});

        $('div.ckeditor_tool').click(function(){
            stopBlur = true;
            setTimeout(function(){stopBlur = false;},200);
            a.find('div.ckeditor').focus();
        });
        a.find('div.ckeditor').focus();

    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = false;
    var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( a.attr('id') );
```

BUT - the editors appear on clicking the right areas, but won't disappear when loosing focus, or save the data ...